# Calling a Lua string with C

Tags: c, string, lua, arm, embedded-language

I'm trying to learn how to use Lua with C, so by now I want to try running a script without loading it from a file, since I don't want to be bothered with messing up with files.
Can anybody tell me which functions do I need to call for executing a simple string or what ever?

Comment: It's "Lua", not "LUA". See http://www.lua.org/about.html#name .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [luaL_dostring](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_dostring) to execute a script from a string.

If you need help with the basics (creating a Lua state, etc.), read part IV of [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/).

Comment: Thank you, by the way do you know anything about displaying an error?

Comment: See how errors are handled in this example: http://www.lua.org/pil/24.1.html
That code uses `luaL_loadbuffer` and `lua_pcall` instead of `luaL_dostring`, but it should work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function in my project to load Lua buffer, following is the code:

```
bool Reader::RunBuffer(const char *buff,char* ret_string,const char *name){
    int error = 0;
    char callname[256] = "";
    if( m_plua == NULL || buff == NULL || ret_string == NULL ) return false;
    if( name == NULL ){
        strcpy(callname,"noname");
    }else{
        strcpy(callname,name);
    }
    error = luaL_loadbuffer(m_plua, buff, strlen(buff),callname) || lua_pcall(m_plua, 0, 1, 0);
    if (error){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", lua_tostring(m_plua, -1));
        lua_pop(m_plua, 1);
    }else{
        sprintf(ret_string, "%s", lua_tostring(m_plua, -1));
    }
    return true;
}
```

This code takes buff, and return ret_string. As @interjay said `luaL_dostring` is a choice.